# Centos 7 --> Track if users attempt to access a folder/directory they do not have access too?

Tags: centos, security, logs, monitoring, administration

If Bob tries to access something like `/home/Code/TopSecret` for example. The system wouldn't allow him to access this without having the permission. I would like to know about these attempts.

Is there a way I can monitor and view these attempts by either modifying `auditctl`? Or, if it is already being monitored, where would I view these attempts?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse `~/.bash_history` for every user: `grep -e "$pattern" /home/*/.bash_history`

To view their sudo commands: `tail /var/log/secure | grep username` or `tail /var/log/secure | grep "$pattern"`

As you figured you can track acces to a path with [auditctl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl). Tried on one of my test systems and this works pretty well and its directlty from the man page:

```
auditctl -w "$path" -a exit,always -S open -F success=0
```

Again you should parse the audit.log with `grep "$pathoffileorfolder" /var/log/audit/audit.log`

Thats about what i would use without installing anything that doesnt come with the distro.

Comment: +1 for `auditctl` example.  -1 for grepping `~/.bash_history` which is too easy for a user to circumvent.  `man ausearch` and `man aureport` for ways to review audit logs as opposed to `grep <pattern> audit.log`.